# permission sp_xp_cmdshell_proxy_account for more than one user who needs to run xp_cmdshell without a sysadmin

Tags: sql-server, cmd, permissions, system-administration, xp-cmdshell

I created a proxy account that xp_cmdshell will run using sp_xp_cmdshell_proxy_account
And I gave one user permission

```
EXEC sp_xp_cmdshell_proxy_account 'Domain\user1'
```

If I give another user too

```
EXEC sp_xp_cmdshell_proxy_account 'Domain\user2'
```

I saw that only one had permission - the last user - user2

```
select * From sys.credentials
```

Does it override the previous user's permission?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sp_xp_cmdshell_proxy_account` does not "give user permissions". This stored procedure specifies the OS security context (proxy account) all non-sysadmin role members that execute `xp_cmdshell`. The SQL Server service account is used when sysadmin role members execute `xp_cmdshell`